# How to pass parameters or values from one jsp page to another jsp page without submiting form

Tags: jsp

first.jsp
I want to send parameter name classn from first.jsp to second.jsp page

Class

```
<select name="classn" onchange="showState(this.value)" >
    <option value="select">--Select--</option>
    <option value="I class">I Class</option>
    <option value="II class">II Class</option>
    <option value="III class">III Class</option>
    <option value="IV class">IV Class</option>
</select>
```

second.jsp

```
<%
    String classname=request.getParameter("classn");
%>
```

But I am not getting the parameter value into classname variable

Answer (score 1):

You need not to submit the form to send the values into another jsp page. In your onchange method call jquery ajax method to send the value to server.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Ur_URL",
    data: { classn: "value" }
})
.done(function( msg ) {
 //If you need anything to return.
});
```

From this you can receive the parameter in your servlet like this.

```
String classname=request.getParameter("classn");
```

Then you can set the value in session variable (to make available all over session). In second.jsp page check whether the session variable available or not, if available do whatever you want. Let me know if this helps you..

Answer (score 0):

Because the second JSP file is sent from the server, you have to send the server this information for it to pass on to the second page. You can add them to the url (?classn=XX, normally with javascript) or you can post them (from a form), but they have to be sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

- In `JSP` if you want server side validation means, after the form submission the values will be send to the server side, if you don't want to submit the form using `submit button` , you also do it by `java-script` function

  ```
  <select id="class" onChange="submit()" action="second" >
   <option value="select">--Select--</option>
   <option value="I class">I Class</option>
   <option value="II class">II Class</option>
   <option value="III class">III Class</option>
   <option value="IV class">IV Class</option>
  </select>
  ```

JavaScript Function

```
function submit()
{
   document.getElementById("class").submit();
   //This will submit the request to `second.jsp` where you can have your validations

}
```

- Another method:  you can  validate the `inputField` by use java script function which is an client side validation in which the input validation can be done.

  ```
  function showState(value)
  {
     //value object hold the input text values
     //Do your validation here
  }
  ```

---